# The original proof of Szemerédi's Theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

Nowadays there are plenty of different proofs of the celebrated Szemerédi's Theorem but for historical reasons I would like to read and understand the original proof. The proof is very tricky and, for instance, he uses a primitive version of the Regularity Lemma (weaker and more complicated), so I would like to find some source with a 'modern' language.

My question is then the following: is there any survey/book/... where the original proof is presented (with more details possibly), apart of course of the original paper?

Comment: I doubt that anybody decides to rewrite such complicated original proof modernizing only language.

Comment: www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/szemeredi_theorem.dvi   : though Tao later states that in this exposition he "was unable to find much of a simplification, and my exposition is probably not that much clearer than the original text". See also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/some-ingredients-in-szemeredis-proof-of-szemeredis-theorem/

Comment: Thank you, that's what exactly the type of thing I was looking for